# Elasticsearch Kibana Date Display Issues

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-5

I have two Elasticsearch date fields that are not showing up correctly in Kibana.  The dates are shipped as longs corresponding to milliseconds since epoch.

For instance, 1513864139000 which corresponds to Thu Dec 21 2017 08:48:59 in my local time is being displayed as December 31st 1969, 19:00:00.000.

There's one additional field, also stored as milliseconds since epoch, that in the Kibana index management is set up as the timestamp for the index.  This field, does show up correctly.

I think I can fix it easily enough by adding a offset and sending the date as an Elasticsearch formatted date string but I was wondering if anyone has run across this and knows a fix.  It would save me from reindexing a substantial amount of data.

I'm on Kibana/Elasticsearch 5.4.

Comment: Seeing the exact same issue with Kibana 6.5.0. Really annoying.